# Windows Mobile App - Play MMS Stream?

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, streaming, mms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Mobile App - Play Stream Over MMS Protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120753/windows-mobile-app-play-stream-over-mms-protocol)

I'm trying to write a Windows Mobile app targeting Windows Mobile 6.x that will stream an internet radio stream delivered via MMS protocol (just one feature among other things).

Does the .NET Compact Framework have built-in controls or API's that will do this?  Or would I need to start looking for a third-party library?

I'm a little confused why this wouldn't be supported in the .NET Compact Framework?  I mean MMS is Microsoft's proprietary Windows streaming protocol.

I'm actually not sure how to stream MP3 over http either.  I have tried this, but it was unsuccessful:

[Some MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562692(VS.85).aspx)

In fact, it is unsuccessful if I navigate to the mobile's Windows Media Player itself and give it the same URL.  However, this same URL does work from the Windows Media Player on my desktop computer.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** So I'm going to repost this question not as "Community Wiki," which I mistakenly checked. I need you guys to have more incentive to answer the question with reputation being involved.

[Link to New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120753/windows-mobile-app-play-stream-over-mms-protocol)

Answer (score 0):

You can download WM6 SDK at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=06111A3A-A651-4745-88EF-3D48091A390B&displaylang=en and you may find sample sources about this kind of application. Based on that sample sources, you can modify and customize the application to your need. May be you also need VS for installing such kind of SDK.

Comment: Yes, I have the WM6 SDK already and you are right, Visual Studio 2005/2008 Professional or higher is required for mobile development.  I did not think to look for any samples that may have installed with the SDK.  I will look there and report back.  Thanks.

Comment: There is no sample dealing with MMS in the SDK (I used PowerShell to do a "grep" for the string "mms" and got back no promising results).

Anyone else knowledgable about Windows Mobile apps and MMS streaming?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Mobile does not come with MMS support.  Windows Mobile only comes with SMS support.  It's up to the OEM's to provide MMS support, most do purchasing some third party MMS application.

So there is no one way to do what you want that will work on all Windows Mobile devices.  A OEM may provide libraries to help, but most likely not.

Comment: So I can use a third-party C library like LibMMS https://launchpad.net/libmms/ in a .NET mobile app?

Comment: Also, I'm not looking for MMS messaging.  I want to stream an internet radio stream delivered via MMS protocol.  I'll clarify that in my question.

Comment: Your right, I misunderstood your question.  Sorry, I know nothing about MMS Streaming.